# Differences of creating sql database through visual studio and sql server management studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am a beginner to ASP.NET and I have created a SQL database using visual studio 2013 and added it to my project.

But in every video tutorial that i find in internet they are creating the database through the SQL server and then add it to their project.

I am having confusion why do they do so if they can create the database through visual studio itself.

Are there are any disadvantages of creating the database through visual studio rather than not creating through sql server? What are the differences in this two aspects?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Just think of Visual Studio and Management studio as two different tools.  Each one has strengths and weaknesses in regards to database development so it comes down to how you like to work.

Comment: are there any weaknesses when hosting the website if i use visual studio rather than sql management studio?

Comment: I would say visual studio is much easier to deploy from.  I think for the most part visual studio is a great tool for developers, and management studio is the better choice for more DBA oriented tasks.

Comment: @hEShaN  for purpose both are same.

Answer (score 0):

In the Microsoft world there are always multiple ways to do things. In the end they usually call the same underlying API functions.

You can also create a database with PowerShell, sqlcmd.exe or your C# code. It is just a matter of choice.

In older versions of Visual Studio there was no way to create a database in SQL Server, so us old folks had to use SQL Management tools and one often stays with what one knows, so people keep using that even though they can do it the Visual Studio now.

But there are often differences what these different tools can do. In Visual Studio you specify a server name and a database name and the database is created with the configured details.

When creating a database in SQL Management Studio or using SQL command `CREATE Database` you can specify many additional settings. You can change these settings later even on a database created with Visual Studio. If for example you want to store the database files in a non-default location you can do specify that when creating it in SQL Management Studio. If you had used VS, you had to move those files later, which can be a pain.